# Sql, about find how much customers

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm have 2 tables: table for customers and table for activity. Im trying to find how many customers have 2 activity specific.
For example, how many customers was bought and arrived to the branch.
(i have line in the activity table for every act that the customer did.)
I tryied something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer INNER JOIN activity 
ON activity.customerid = customer.id 
WHERE activity.activity = 'arrived' AND activity.activity = 'bought'
```

But its not working.
Can you help me please?

Comment: add an alias to make it inambigous

Comment: Your conditions are mutually exclusive; maybe use OR instead of AND?

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: How isn't it working? Are you getting an error or is it just not counting them? I would assume to try SELECT customer.id instead of count(*) to check if you are getting any rows (which presumably you aren't) and then check whether your WHERE conditions are being met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after our comments, I've tested it out in MySQL Workbench, and it did work. I didn't include the JOINS in the SQL, because you are only counting, and they aren't needed. This is what I got working:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activity
    WHERE activity = 'arrived' AND
    customerid IN 
       (SELECT DISTINCT(customerid) FROM activity
            WHERE activity = 'bought');
```

[image]

In my table, I put 2 rows, both with customerid of 1. One had "arrived" as the activity, the other had "bought" and it correctly gave me an answer of 1. I'm not sure why PHPMyAdmin is hanging, but it definitely works

Comment: but i need the number of customer that arrived to the branch AND bought.. not the number of customer was arrive OR buy... are you understand?

Comment: Ahh okay I got you, that complicates things slightly. I've edited my answer with something I think should work. Hasn't been tested though

Comment: Can you try replacing the `IN` with an equals sign?

Comment: yes, error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Hmm, I'm curious why it didn't work before then? Was an error message given for the SQL statement, with the `IN`?

Comment: One last try, try replacing `IN` with `= ANY` and see what happens then

Comment: When you say it crashes, what exactly happens?

Comment: the phpmyadmin is write: "loading..." for a alwyis

Comment: thank you! its look great but i have something like 110K customer and more than 300K activities, do you know how can do it faster?

Comment: I've added the only optimization I can think of. It should only do 2 passes of the activity table anyway, so shouldn't be taking horrendously long

Comment: After doing some reading, using 'EXISTS' instead of 'IN' may be better optimized, please give it a go and let me know if there's any difference. I don't have any tables of that size to personally test on!

Answer (score 0):

You will find that `id` is reserved name.

It's wise to get in the habit of encapsulating (adding backticks) to your tables and column names e.g:

```
`customer`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

the following will work

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer where customer.id in (select activity.customerid from activity where activity.activity = 'arrived' AND activity.activity = 'bought' group by activity.customerid)

Read up on sub queries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

What the SQL in the brackets is trying to do is get the customers with the correct activitys from the activity table. I use a group by as the sql in brackets  will return multiple rows for the customer and you only want one row per customer. With the ids that are returned you then lookup the customers in the customer table.

Comment: Hi thank you! but its steel not working.. the result is 0 and this is not true.